# Deploy smart contract on Ropsten using truffle-hdwallet-provider

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

I have 7 smart contracts to deploy on the Ropsten network.

I am using **truffle-hdwallet-provider** and below is the content of my **truffle.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
    enabled: true,
    runs: 200
 }
},
networks: {
 ropsten: {
  provider: function() {
    return new HDWalletProvider(
      process.env.MNENONIC,
      `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
      );
    },
    gasPrice: 250000000000,
    network_id: 3
  }
 }
};
```

Then I run the following command:

```
truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

but I get the following response:

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

Fine, it stated I have insufficient fund and my fund was 1.509 Ether at the time. So can I assume the cost to deploy all my contracts is more than 1.509 Ether (that's more than USD163!)?

Appreciate if someone can guide me.

Comment: Does the error appear if you try to deploy to ganache? How much is the block gas limit in your blockchain? Truffle used to have around 4.7M as default, if your chain is less it will fail. Another possible cause is if you have a library that is not linked. There're many errors that map to the same message. Add some way to try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find out Gas Usage : https://github.com/cgewecke/eth-gas-reporter

Also just try removing gasprice from truffle file and try again

Comment: Thanks sumit!
I installed the **eth-gas-reporter**.

I run `truffle develop` on one terminal window and `truffle mocha` on the other window.

But I got "Could not connect to your Ethereum client".

I guess I do not know how to use it.

Comment: I added the following in my truffle.js:
    mocha: {
        reporter: "eth-gas-reporter",
        reporterOptions: {
        currency: "USD",
        gasPrice: 21
       }}

ok now I get from terminal output:
"Using network development"
"Network is up to date"